# RPI Screen Setup

Tags: screen

I am thinking about getting [this screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045IIZKU). It is RCA I believe and so I will need a converter.  If I bought that screen with [this](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-15489) do you think that would work? Also, with that setup how is the screen being powered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stereo-to-RCA cable will work, and as per the top review of the screen (did you read it?) this screen works perfectly fine with an rPi, but you need a 12V powersource from what I understand:

> This monitor, like I've put in the title, was bought for a Raspberry
>   Pi. I didn't want to spend on anything larger than what was needed,
>   and didn't want to connect to a TV at all, since the Pi is just meant
>   to be a fun, homebrew-style computer, and I wanted to build it as
>   cheaply as possible. With that said, the monitor is not only cheap,
>   but it WORKS and works well.
>
> First of all, in describing it, the screen size that you will get out
>   of the box is about the size of a PalmPilot's (close to 3.5"), and it
>   will come with a flexible arm and mini-stand attached to it that you
>   can adjust however you like, with a sticker underneath in case you
>   want to mount it to anything. In short, it is really a baby LCD flat
>   panel.
>
> On the back are three buttons: Menu, +, and -. There is no
>   menu--simply press the buttons to alternate between Brightness,
>   Contrast, and "Colorast" (or how much color you want--0 is grayscale),
>   and finally OK or Reset. With that said, settings are very simple to
>   configure on it.
>
> Now, we get to the last (and fun) part. You can splice two cords
>   together to get power if you wish, but I simply connected a 1.0 A
>   (1000 mA), 12 V (and under 4 W) power adapter, which works efficiently
>   well. I'm mentioning this to be helpful in case anyone else wants to
>   connect this to their favorite little computer using an easier method.
>   :) You can easily connect any spare yellow RCA video cable, and the
>   picture is surprisingly clear! To get specific, with good enough eyes,
>   you can read 12 pt text in Sans or Monospace (though anything lower
>   becomes harder to read--although I can still read size 10) and this
>   monitor drives a 656x416 resolution according to xrandr (a little bit
>   under 640x480). This is with overscan on (which means the screen puts
>   an artifical box around the screen so it fits better) and I recommend
>   you turn this on. Without it, maximized windows will exceed the screen
>   space, making things a bit monotonous. Now, without overscan, it does
>   about 712 instead of 656 if I remember right. This is totally up to
>   you. Also, I find tilting it up a bit on a desk, and sitting closer to
>   it helps make the experience a bit better.
>
> And so far... all my shells show up clearly, and everything seems to
>   be working fine. There's barely any flicker I can see with my
>   configuration, and it displays nicely. With all this said, that is the
>   story thus far with this screen connected to a Raspberry Pi as a
>   monitor, and I hope others find this helpful when setting it up. :)

And if you need rPi specific modding instructions for the powersource, [they are posted on raspberryPi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=17651).